# Rigify Generated Rig just absolutely refusing to bind to mesh

Tags: mesh, rigging, armature, bones, rigify

[image][image: full screenshot]

***2 Full screenshots added***

I made a mesh for a character on Blender 3.6.1 and I have followed about twenty tutorials on youtube on getting the Rigify rig to attach to the mesh. I have already merged vertices and simplified and I just do not know what I could possibly be missing at this point. Any tips or tricks would be appreciated for sure!

I am using the new curves system for the hair and so the hair is not joined but merely parented to the mesh but the sweater and jeans and shoes were joined onto the body which was sculpted separately. The vertex count is only 54114 if the hair stays as curves and if I convert the hair curves to mesh it jumps up to like 13 million.

Please help!

[[image: proof of parenthoodrig not attached to mesh][image: mesh with generated rig in pose mode]

Comment: Please use proper screenshots rather than taking photos of your screen. In Blender, use the Window > Save Screenshot or Save Screenshot (Editor) menu. (The 'Editor' one allows you to save just one area of the screen by clicking on it.)  There's a good tutorial showing fixes for problems with rigify [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FuiY0wtxdHQ).

Comment: thank you for the tip! I added a full screenshot now

Comment: I'd suggest you work your way through [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FuiY0wtxdHQ) video which covers most of the common problems with getting Rigify to behave. If you still have problems you may need to share your blend  file if it isn't too large. You can share it via https://blend-exchange.com/ if it's smaller than 30Meg following the instructions there to copy the link to your question into the field on that page and it will then appear in your question.